# Double differentiation with implicit dependencies

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

Suppose we have a function $u(x,y)$ which we re-define wrt another variable $\omega$, such that $u(x,y)=u(\omega(x,y))$ and there is an implicit relation between $\omega$, $x$ and $y$,

$x-p(\omega)y=0$

The double derivatives needs to be calculated. The solution I found somewhere was,

$u_{,yy}= \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \left(p(\omega)^2\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} u'(\omega)\right)$ , where $u'(\omega)$ is differentiation wrt $\omega$

What I am getting by chain rule is,

$u_{,yy}=p(\omega) \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \left(p(\omega)\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} u'(\omega)\right)$

Please let me know if I am missing something here. Thanks.

Comment: $f(x,y)=f(\omega)$ makes no sense as $f$ is a function of two variables. To avoid confusion you should write $g(\omega):=f(x(\omega),y(\omega))$. But I don't think the first two lines play any further part, do they? Personally I'd write $v(x,y):=u(\omega(x,y))$  and then for $v_{yy}$ I'd get the same as you did. But is that exactly what is being asserted "somewhere"?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for the suggestion but yes, the first two lines are don't really matter much. I came across this in a mechanics paper. It is exactly what they have given. I want to go ahead with my own solution but if we follow chain rule, $u_{,xy} \neq u_{,yx}$ which is physically not possible.

Comment: I think that what I do not understand is the paper's notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}$. When you use it I think you mean the same as $'$; at least that's how I interpreted it and got the same as you.